# SWI-Prolog - Unit testing library plunit - How is forall option used?

Tags: unit-testing, prolog, swi-prolog, parameterized-unit-test, plunit

For my lexer ([tokenizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization)) all of the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) [7-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#7-bit_codes) characters (0x00 to 0x7F) have a specific token. As SWI-Prolog [supports](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=unicodesyntax) [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), the character codes go from 0x0000 to 0xFFFF.

In my lexer, since there are many characters that will not map to a specific token there is an unknown token (tokUnknown).

To ensure that all of the characters with code between 0 and 127 (0x00 to 0x7F) do not have  `tokUnknown`, test cases are needed.

The test case needs a simple lexer to convert the character to a token.

```
tokenizer_unknown(Token) -->
    (
        white_space_char(W), !, white_space(W, S),
        { Token = tokWhitespace(S) }
    ;
        [S],
        { special_character(S,Token) }
    ;
        digit(D), !, number(D, N),
        { Token = tokNumber(N) }
    ;
        letter(L), !, word(L, W),
        { Token = tokWord(W) }
    ;
        [_],
        { Token = tokUnknown }
    ), !.
```

Here is the test case for the character with code 0.

```
:- begin_tests(unknown).

test(001) :-
    Code = 0,
    char_code(Char,Code),
    Chars = [Char],
    phrase(tokenizer_unknown(Token),Chars,Rest),
    assertion(Rest == []),
    assertion(Token \== tokUnknown).

:- end_tests(unknown).
```

Writing test in this manner requires 128 different test to check for `tokUnknown`.

SWI-Prolog unit testing library [plunit](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27)) has an option [forall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=unitbox) to generate data.

Based on the documentation the test should look like this:

```
test(002, [forall(???)]) :-
    char_code(Char,Code),
    Chars = [Char],
    phrase(tokenizer_unknown(Token),Chars,Rest),
    assertion(Rest == []),
    assertion(Token \== tokUnknown).
```

Can the `forall` option be used to write just one test case instead of 128 individual test cases for this test series?

Can you give a working version of the test case using forall?

---

Follow-up

The template for forall is `forall(:Generator)`.

When I first saw this I was totally confused and almost walked away going back to writing large numbers of test, but stuck with it knowing how valuable and easily this should be for making parameterized tests, e.g. [JUnit 5](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests)  or [NUnit 3](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parameterized-Tests). Parameterized  test can then be used for [fuzzing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing) and fuzzing can be enhanced to generate [counter examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexample), e.g. [QuickCheck](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/), [FsCheck](https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck)

---

Example 1

In the hard coded test

```
test(001) :-
    Code = 0,
    char_code(Char,Code),
    Chars = [Char],
    phrase(tokenizer_unknown(Token),Chars,Rest),
    assertion(Rest == []),
    assertion(Token \== tokUnknown).
```

I wanted to make `Code` a variable that changed for each test. I also knew the constraints for `Code`, i.e. 0 to 127.

So for this simple generator all that was needed was a predicate that generated values from 0 to 127 when called and returned them as a variable, e.g. `Code`.

[between/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=between/3) fills the requirement, e.g.

```
?- between(0,3,Code).
Code = 0 ;
Code = 1 ;
Code = 2 ;
Code = 3.
```

As can be seen by looking at the answer, just give the predicate to `forall`, e.g.

```
forall(between(0, 127, Code))
```

---

Example 2

This test is to check that all individual [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) characters or sequence of whitespace characters for ASCII 7-bit characters return as `tokWhitespace` and that the whitespace character(s) are a string value of the token.

The custom with whitespace tokens is not to include the characters in the token, but here they are included because it is easier to remove them if needed then wonder why the OP didn't do it. Since this is for learning they are included.

Hard coded tests

```
:- begin_tests(white_space).

test(001) :-
    String = "\t",
    string_codes(String,Codes),
    phrase(whitespace(Tokens),Codes,Rest),
    assertion(Tokens == tokWhitespace("\t")),
    assertion(Rest == []).

test(011) :-
    String = "\t\r",
    string_codes(String,Codes),
    phrase(whitespace(Tokens),Codes,Rest),
    assertion(Tokens == tokWhitespace("\t\r")),
    assertion(Rest == []).

test(043) :-
    String = "\s\s\s",
    string_codes(String,Codes),
    phrase(whitespace(Tokens),Codes,Rest),
    assertion(Tokens == tokWhitespace("\s\s\s")),
    assertion(Rest == []).

:- end_tests(white_space).
```

In this example the variables are `String`, e.g. `"\t"`, and the value in the token `tokWhitespace`, e.g. `"\t"`.

The single whitespace characters are:

```
?- code_type(Char,space).
Char = 9 ;        % tokHorizontalTab   \t
Char = 10 ;       % tokLineFeed        \n
Char = 11 ;       % tokVerticalTab     \v
Char = 12 ;       % tokFormFeed        \f
Char = 13 ;       % tokCarriageReturn  \r
Char = 32 ;       % tokSpace           \s
Char = 160 ;      % Yes, there are space characters defined beyond 7-bit ASCII. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode
Char = 5760 ; 
...
```

One lesson learned from decades of writing lexer/tokenization tests is that each individual character needs to be tested. Also the test should not generate the values in the same manner as the check in lexer/tokenizer. In this case the test should not rely on `code_type/2` because that is used in the lexer/tokenizer and if `code_type/2` where some how to get a bug the tests would not detect it. So the test cases will get the characters via a different means, in this example they will be from a list.

A second lesson learned from decades of testing recursive code is that the test needs to test at least three levels deep. In this example the test of whitespace characters will test sequences up to three characters.

A third lesson is that using functional composition with functions such as combinations, permutations, type constructors, and type destructors, etc. reduce the [combinatorial explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion) of writing test data generators; conversely they contribute to combinatorial explosion of test cases. To do this in Prolog requires translating functional concepts to Prolog predicates.

Based on these lessons some helper predicates are needed.

```
comb(0,_,[]).
comb(N,[X|T],[X|Comb]) :-
    N>0,
    N1 is N-1,
    comb(N1,T,Comb).
comb(N,[_|T],Comb) :-
    N>0,
    comb(N,T,Comb).

variation_string(N,L,String) :-
    between(1,N,N0),
    comb(N0,L,L1),
    permutation(L1,L2),
    string_chars(String,L2).

variation_number(N,L,String,Number) :-
    between(1,N,N0),
    comb(N0,L,L1),
    permutation(L1,L2),
    string_chars(String,L2),
    number_chars(Number,L2).
```

Example usage:

```
?- variation_string(3,['\t','\r','\n'],String).
String = "\t" ;
String = "\r" ;
String = "\n" ;
String = "\t\r" ;
String = "\r\t" ;
String = "\t\n" ;
String = "\n\t" ;
String = "\r\n" ;
String = "\n\r" ;
String = "\t\r\n" ;
String = "\t\n\r" ;
String = "\r\t\n" ;
String = "\r\n\t" ;
String = "\n\t\r" ;
String = "\n\r\t" ;
false.
```

To keep the reading of `forall` simpler a helper predicate is created.

```
generator_ascii_7bit_char_type_white(R) :-
    variation_string(3,['\t','\n','\v','\f','\r','\s'],R).
```

Now to simply use the generator with `forall` in the test.

```
:- begin_tests(white_space).

test(000, [forall(generator_ascii_7bit_char_type_white(String))]) :-
    string_codes(String,Codes),
    phrase(whitespace(Tokens),Codes,Rest),
    assertion(Tokens == tokWhitespace(String)),
    assertion(Rest == []).

:- end_tests(white_space).
```

With such little code all these test were created and run (each dot represents a separate test case).

```
% PL-Unit: white_space ............................................................................................................................................................ done
```

---

Example 3

This example [test a non-deterministic predicate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=testnondet) so needs to use [findall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions). This also has two input parameters and two output parameters for the predicate.

The signature of findall/3 is

```
findall(+Template, :Goal, -Bag)
```

To use two values with `finall/3` the `Template` is not a tuple, e.g. `(A,B)`, but a list, e.g. `[A,B]`, and the `Bag` is a list of list, e.g. `[["1",1],["2",2]]` where each item in the list is a result and items in the inner list are the values for corresponding `Template` parameters.

This example test `variation_number/4`

```
:- begin_tests(variation_number_4).

variation_number_4(0,[],[]).
variation_number_4(1,[],[]).
variation_number_4(2,[],[]).
variation_number_4(3,[],[]).
variation_number_4(0,['1'],[]).
variation_number_4(1,['1'],[["1",1]]).
variation_number_4(2,['1'],[["1",1]]).
variation_number_4(3,['1'],[["1",1]]).
variation_number_4(0,['1','2'],[]).
variation_number_4(1,['1','2'],[["1",1],["2",2]]).
variation_number_4(2,['1','2'],[["1",1],["2",2],["12",12],["21",21]]).
variation_number_4(3,['1','2'],[["1",1],["2",2],["12",12],["21",21]]).
variation_number_4(0,['1','2','3'],[]).
variation_number_4(1,['1','2','3'],[["1",1],["2",2],["3",3]]).
variation_number_4(2,['1','2','3'],[["1",1],["2",2],["3",3],["12",12],["21",21],["13",13],["31",31],["23",23],["32",32]]).
variation_number_4(3,['1','2','3'],[["1",1],["2",2],["3",3],["12",12],["21",21],["13",13],["31",31],["23",23],["32",32],["123",123],["132",132],["213",213],["231",231],["312",312],["321",321]]).
variation_number_4(0,['1','2','3','4'],[]).
variation_number_4(1,['1','2','3','4'],[["1",1],["2",2],["3",3],["4",4]]).
variation_number_4(2,['1','2','3','4'],[["1",1],["2",2],["3",3],["4",4],["12",12],["21",21],["13",13],["31",31],["14",14],["41",41],["23",23],["32",32],["24",24],["42",42],["34",34],["43",43]]).
variation_number_4(3,['1','2','3','4'],[["1",1],["2",2],["3",3],["4",4],["12",12],["21",21],["13",13],["31",31],["14",14],["41",41],["23",23],["32",32],["24",24],["42",42],["34",34],["43",43],["123",123],["132",132],["213",213],["231",231],["312",312],["321",321],["124",124],["142",142],["214",214],["241",241],["412",412],["421",421],["134",134],["143",143],["314",314],["341",341],["413",413],["431",431],["234",234],["243",243],["324",324],["342",342],["423",423],["432",432]]).

test(000, forall(variation_number_4(Len,L,R0s))) :-
    findall([R,N],variation_number(Len,L,R,N),Rs),
    assertion(Rs == R0s).

:- end_tests(variation_number_4).
```

Comment: Is there benefit to using `phrase/3` and asserting `Rest == []` over just using `phrase/2`?

Comment: @DanielLyons Good question that should be brought into the open. In a production environment I would use `phrase/2` as the DCG should have all of the bugs taken out. For testing DCGs I use `phrase/3` almost exclusively because I want to make sure that the DCG did not miss something. If I know the DCG covers all variations of the input to the end then `Rest` should always be `[]`. With test cases accuracy and completeness trumps speed and checking `Rest` is a free completeness bonus so, I take advantage of it.  It does sometimes catch errors.

Comment: I believe the implementation is `phrase(X,Y) :- phrase(X, Y, []).` though, so I'm not sure there's a benefit there. The test would surely fail if the DCG failed, right?

Comment: Yeah, [the implementation in SWI](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/boot/dcg.pl?show=src#phrase/2) is as I said.

Comment: I'm saying `phrase(digits(Tokens), Chars, Rest), assertion(Rest == [])` is probably as good as `phrase(digits(Tokens), Chars)` unless the assertion buys you something more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the assertions are not correct. They should be:

```
...
assertion(Rest == []),
assertion(Token \== tokUnknown).
```

Otherwise a bug that would return `Rest` or `Token` unbound would not be detected by the test.

Regarding your question for the `forall/1` option, I would expect the following to work (not tried, however):

```
test(002, [forall(between(0, 127, Code))]) :-
    char_code(Char, Code),
    phrase(tokenizer_unknown(Token), [Char], Rest),
    assertion(Rest == []),
    assertion(Token \== tokUnknown).
```

Comment: I knew the answer before I posted it. These answers should be easily found and are not so I am asking them so that others can get past the classroom problems. Thanks for the note about the assertion comparison, now that  you brought it to the front it is obviously wrong.